# T-SQL Tree Search Select from set of nodes if they are under a parent

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, recursive-query, tree-search

T-SQL Tree Search

Select from set of nodes if they are under a parent

I have a very large tree in a MSSQL Db (80000+) records. My client has requested a quick search of the tree via a text `LIKE` command.  The `LIKE` command returns < 500 records.

Is there some recursive command that will check the tree of each quickly to see if they are under a particular node?

Edit:
I thought it was fairly clear however....

I am on SQL Server 2005.

```
Table Schema
 - (pK) Id
 - (fK) ParentId
 - FirstName
 - LastName
```

I have recursive calls that are able to go down several levels quickly. however to do the Name search I would have to poll the entire tree which can be several hundred levels deep and is not an option. I was hoping for help designing a query so I can search the entire table first for the name match and filter the records that are not part of the tree in question.

Comment: Please, show us your table schema, what database engine and version you are using (DB2, SQL Server?). AS it is, your question might be closed as "Not a Real Question"

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a recursive CTE -- do you need a code example?

Like this (this code was tested)

```
WITH recurseTree AS
(
   SELECT * 
   FROM tableName
   WHERE Id = @parentID
   UNION ALL
   SELECT c.*
   FROM tableName c
   JOIN recurseTree p ON c.parentID = p.id
)
SELECT * 
FROM recurseTree
```

Note : More recient versions (2008+) give you a special datatype ([hierarchyid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677290%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)) for doing fast tree traversals.  This would probably be the best way to go, anything else is not going to be as fast.  Upgrade!!

Comment: That would be great. We have been attempting to write it, but have not quite got it right yet.

Comment: You can't make recursive calls from a subquery, at least not in SQL Server 2005.  Not sure about later versions.

Comment: I'm talking about the fact that if you try to run this query, SQL Server will give you the following error:  `Recursive references are not allowed in subqueries.`

Comment: @JeremyWiggins - Good catch, as I said, over a year.  This code I tested.

Answer (score 1):

This should help you:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT Id, ParentId, FirstName, LastName
    FROM YourTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT B.Id, B.ParentId, B.FirstName, B.LastName
    FROM CTE A 
    INNER JOIN YourTable B
    ON A.ParentId = B.Id
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE FirstName LIKE '%something%'
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: I have this but it is slow in this code you gather several thousand records (the whole sub-tree under the node in question) and then filter it. If we can go the other way, determine which nodes in a set are under a parent node it could be much faster.